# How to Calling app ui for initiator and responder

Tags: java, android, xml, service

Hi Everyone i am working on a Calling app but i am facing one issue i want to open two different Ui or view.One for person who make call like this
[image: Who make Call]

and one for person who receive the call like this
[image: Who receive the call]

as you guys see these Ui are little different.I have both the Ui, but the problem is that my both the Ui are opening on a same window.

Like when a person makes call the first Ui open and then the second Ui also open for the same user.How to open different layouts for each user one for person who makes call and one for the person who gets the call.
If you are npt sure to learn my question its the same as Fb meassenger calling or whats app calling where sender and responder have different Ui.

Please provide me the why where i can achieve this.

Comment: @Imran Ali pleas etag someone who guide me

Comment: which platform you are developing for android or ios?, please tag your question accordingly

Comment: @ImranAli for android